# Writing mp4 file into file using DirectShow

Tags: directshow, directshow.net

I use GraphEdit program for taking **live videostreams** from **rtsp sorce** and write that file in to local storage.

My Graph is rougly like this:

```
RtspSourceFilter -> VideoDecoder(MPG4) -> FileWriter(*.mp4) 
(not work)
RtspSourceFilter -> VideoDecoder(MPG4) -> VideoEncoder(MPG-2)->FileWriter(*.mp4) 

( frame rate is wrong, too fast, and why decode and encode same file to write disk)
```

I can not able to enter any property such as fps to  **FileWriter**...

Any advice to record video to disk using direct show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to use a mp4 muxer before your FileWriter filter. Your graph could be something like:

RtspSourceFilter->mp4 muxer->FileWriter

You can try with the free [GDCL mp4 muxer/demuxer](http://www.gdcl.co.uk/index.htm) or [Haalis Matroska Muxer](http://matroska.org/downloads/windows.html). For the last one you will need to configure it to output mp4.